# Ascx in different folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an web application that uses themes and different master pages. Each master page is at the shared folder with their names; such as Shared\Themes\MyTheme\Site.master
and the views are at \ControllerName\ListUsers.aspx

In the controller; I call the view : return View("ListUsers",ThemeEngine.MasterPage,Model);
So far everything works fine; however when I try to call RenderPartial inside the ListUsers, I am getting usercontrol can't be found error because my user controls are at the master page folder such as \Shared\Themes\MyTheme\SingleUser.ascx
Is there a way to tell the framework to look for the user controls in a different folder than \Shared but \Shared\ThemeNAme  etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  You can specify the path to the View using the virtual root.  There's nothing stopping you from passing in a full path.

```
return View("~/Shared/Themes/MyTheme/SingleUser.ascx");
```

Comment: Is there any problem that I might have such as routing changes etc witch this?

Answer (score 1):

[How to change default view location scheme in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc)