# ASP.Net MVC3/4 multiple templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

There is any way to change the defualt views path in MVC3/4. i.e: The Url `http://localhost:000/Home` (the controller Home) will represent the view at `Views/Style1/Home/Action`.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: This sounds like a use case for areas.

Comment: Not exactly, I edited the message

Comment: OK, why will a `RedirectToAction` result not work here?

Comment: I think that is something with the RazorViewEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that I understand the question better after the edit, I think this is what you're looking for:

You can change the ViewLocation in Application_Start().
The example below assumes use of the Razor View Engine.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine { ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/Style1/{1}/{0}.cshtml" } } );
```

*Answer was partially derived and referenced from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735240/change-the-views-location)*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the Default route for your application to use a different base path. You can typically set the route in the Global.asax in the RegisterRoutes method.

Example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "Style1/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: It just changes the mapping method of the URL

Comment: Ah, my answer doesn't really apply after the original message edit.