# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Setting up routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm migrating an ASP.NET web forms application to ASP.NET MVC 3. I kind of understand routing, but I sort of don't. In my application, I have created three .cshtml files in the directory located at /internal/products/find/. For the sake of demonstration, those .cshtml files are named "view1.cshtml", "view2.cshtml", and "view3.cshtml".

I have a controller named "InternalController". My goal is to use InternalController for all of the locations inside the /internal path. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is allowed. I assume it is. Either way, at this time, I have the following in InternalController:

```
public ActionResult View1()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult View2()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult View3()
{
  return View();
}
```

In my global.asax.cs file, I'm trying to register the routes to these views as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "View1",
  "{controller}/products/find/view1",
  new { controller = "Internal", action = "View1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "View2",
  "{controller}/products/find/view2",
  new { controller = "Internal", action = "View2" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "View3",
  "{controller}/products/find/view3",
  new { controller = "Internal", action = "View3" }
);
```

Whenever I try to visit /internal/products/find/view1 in my browser, I see the ASP.NET error screen and it says:

*The view 'View1' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/internal/View1.aspx
~/Views/internal/View1.ascx
~/Views/Shared/View1.aspx
~/Views/Shared/View1.ascx
~/Views/dashboard/View1.cshtml
~/Views/dashboard/View1.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/View1.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/View1.vbhtml*

What am I doing wrong? The path /internal/products/find/view1 is the most important part for me. Ideally, I would like to expose that in InternalController everytime. But I'm having a rough go at it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "View1",
  "{controller}/products/find/{action}",
  new { controller = "Internal", action = "View1" }
);
```

it means that whenever user writes into his browser:

```
http://mysite.com/blahblah/products/find/blahblahview
```

it will activate action **view1** inside controller blahblahview. But it doesn't mean that view1.cshtml file is at that path. Actually, asp.net mvc looks for views at directories defined by convention...and convetion is:

```
~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName
```

so, your view should be in a folder:

```
~/Views/Internal/View1.cshtml
```

Unlike ASP.NET WebForms you are used to, ASP.NET MVC is pretty much driven by naming conventions as you could probably see (you always name your controllers like BlahBlah**Controller**, you always place your views inside Views folder etc... Read some tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started) and catch up with basics.

Comment: My .cshtml files are located in the /products/find directory. How do I update my controllers or routes to use those views?

Comment: I wouldn't do that (just copy your files to default view folder), but if you really want to do it, here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc