# Bundling and concatenation with gulp-useref Durandal and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, gulp, durandal-2.0, gulp-useref

I have a `Durandal 2` app based on `ASP.NET MVC 5` and `Web API`, with the  initial `Index.cshtml` (on `HomeController`) being served through the MVC router. From then on it's all regular html views being handled by the Durandal router.

Anyway, I'm trying to use [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to concatenate all `css` and `js` files. I've got everything working and `gulp-useref` drops the newly concatenated files and an `index.cshtml` with the updated script and stylesheet references in a `dist` folder.

Of course, for the application to work I need the updated `index.cshtml` back in `Views/Home/`. I have created a "copy" task with `gulp` that does just that; it overwrites the original `index.cshtml` and fixes the paths to the concatenated `js` and `css` files.
That works as well, but since `useref` removes the html comments that mark the spot where it should insert the references to the concatenated files, the process is not repeatable.

Let me illustrate with some code.

In my `Index.cshtml` I have:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <!-- build:js js/lib.js-->

      <script src="/bower_components/numeral/languages.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/typeahead.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/knockout-bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/knockout-extenders.js"></script>

      <!-- endbuild -->
   </body>
</html>
```

This is where `gulp-useref` will place the updated script reference so it will end up looking like this:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>   
      <script src="/js/lib.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, `useref` removes the html comments so if I overwrite the original `index.cshtml` with this file, `useref` will not know where to place the updated script tag. And if I don't overwrite the original `index.cshtml`, the application will not be using the concatenated files.

I'm new to `gulp` so I might be going at this in the completely wrong way, but **how can I make sure that my `/Views/Home/index.cshtml` uses the concatenated files in an automated manner?**

Or, alternatively, *is there a better approach for what I'm trying to do, namely, get everything ready for deployment?*

Here are my relevant `gulp` tasks, for reference:

```
gulp.task("optimize-for-deployment", function () {
    var assets = $.useref.assets({ searchPath: "./" });
    var cssFilter = $.filter("**/*.css");
    var jsFilter = $.filter("**/*.js");

    return gulp
        .src(config.index)
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.appDist));
});

// copy the updated index.cshtml to Views/Home/
gulp.task("copy-for-deployment", ["optimize-for-deployment"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.appDist + "index.cshtml")
      .pipe($.replacePath(/js\/lib.js/, "/app/dist/js/lib.js"))
        .pipe($.replacePath(/style\/app.css/, "/app/dist/style/app.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is 'better' approach or the best solution but you could use something like a template for your index file. So you would have an `Index-template.cshtml` with al your html comments which you use to create your `Index.cshtml` every time in your `gulp` tasks.

This way you can overwrite your `Index.cshtml` and keep your template with al your html comments.

Comment: How do you switch between debug and release in this case? If one was to use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to .net mvc and trying to do the exact thing Sergi. If you modified the default view location scheme to include your dist folder ([How to change default view location scheme in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794)), would .net know to include the dist folder and compile those `.cshtml` files?

Comment: yes, but I would still have the same problem, namely that the  `Index.cshtml` that I use during development would be overwritten by the gulp tasks when deploying. It would just be happening in a different location.