# How to make ASP.NET invalid partialview paths strongly typed, not compile or give/warning?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I make use of ASP.NET 5 Areas.

In the default ASP.NET 5 project you have `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` in the `Views\Shared` folder

I can refer to it in my `Areas\AreaName\Views\controllername\MyView.cshtml`

as

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
```

Questions:

1. **Why** can I refer to its path directly and not be forced to use

   ```
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml"}
   ```

   I ask because it is sometimes confusing where it comes from as it is not an relative path. 
   Is there a setting somewhere to enable/disable this behavior.
2. I have various of my own scripts in location in `Views\Shared` as well as in my area's view folder `Areas\MyArea\Views\MyControllerName\`. If I have the same partial view name as in the `Views\Shared` folder will it take precendence?
3. Is there a way to make the location strongly typed (i.e. give build error if not exist) or is using C# constants the best way around this?
   e.g.

   ```
   @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartialNotExist"); }
   ```

does not give an error or warning or red line underneath

Comment: Because the ViewEngine always search the `Views\Shared` folder if the view is not found in the specific controller's view folder

Comment: If you want to configure where views are searched, you can create your own as per [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to make it strongly typed?