# Create multiple views and access with single action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i am having my views separated under subfolder, i have only one Action method in controller, i have my view names in the database, when i call the action method by passing the parameter (for instance: id = 1), it will fetch the view name from the database and the respective view will be load.

```
public ActionResult Index(int FormId)
 {
   var getViews = db.fetchViews.where id = 1; //get views from db
   return view(getviews.viewName);
 }
```

This is my views in the solution.

[image]

while i call the view from action method it says unable to find the views.

i cannot hardcode the subfolder in the Action method like this,

```
return View("~/Views/Form/Customer1/getviews.viewName");
```

any ideas would be appreciate...

Comment: If you were to move all the views to directly under the **Form** directory it would work as expected, without requiring hard-coding of the path.

Comment: @TravisSchettler but i have to separate my views into subfolders thats the motto.

Comment: can you set view full path in db ?

Comment: no man its not possible @Musthaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't move the views to the directory that the razor view engine is looking for, you can try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int FormId)
{
    var getViews = db.fetchViews.where id = 1; //get views from db
    var viewpath = string.Format("~/Views/Form/{0}/{0}", getviews.viewName);
    return View(viewpath);
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom RazorViewEngine that could search for the view in a subdirectory of the same name.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc) has a method of adding search view locations to the razor view engine, your custom search view format would be something like this:

```
new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}/{0}.cshtml"
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of RazorViewEngine that search for view, so can i have any alternatives?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an SO post that gives a method to add custom view locations to the existing razor view engine.

Comment: i didn't use this Razor Engine search rather i would go with your string format method which is more simple...

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public ActionResult Index(int FormId)
{
    var viewName = "~/Views/Form/Customer" + FormId + "/customer" + FormId;
    return View(viewName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the searching of views to be according to what you want, you can inherit the RazorViewEngine and modify the path where Razor will look at. You may see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9840910/1504480)