# Do the views need to be in specific folders in order for an ASP.NET MVC project to work properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-views

For an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, is there some kind of priority ranking between views?

And do they need to be in separate folders within the project?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "priority ranking"? You use one view or another based exclusively on it's file path. They don't need to be in separate folders, but doing so is how MVC works by default, and if you want it to work in any other way you need to configure it as such

Comment: OK second part of your comment is the answer of the question I was asking myself.
Thank you for your help

Comment: By priority ranking I mean views that may be processed first by the browser.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am answering a year later but I should say "Yes there is!" to your first question. The locations are listed at a string list called `ViewLocationFormats` in the `RazorViewEngin`. You can even change the list by inheriting the `RazorViewEngine`, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74523733/customizing-cshtml-for-each-customer/74523791#74523791) or even [changing the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909794/how-to-change-default-view-location-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc)
So the answer to your second question is that they should be anywhere as long as the containing folder listed in the view locations of the used `RazorViewEngine`.