# c# .net Core MVC customize text per customer and localization multi-tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, customization, multi-tenant

I have a c# .net MVC site, and I have correctly setup localization with resource files to work.

I have the following files which change the content when the culture changes:
HelpText.en.resx
HelpText.fr.resx

I now have a scenario where a second customer wants to customize some of the text elements.
What I thought I could achieve was something like the following:

HelpText.Cust1.en.resx
HelpText.Cust1.fr.resx

When the text was not found in the Cust1 resx, it would default back to the original one.

This doesn't seem possible utilizing resx.

How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using resources is not the best way to do so. Think about situations in which the client needs more changes to a view than just a text. (e.g. style,images,...). One proven technique is having a way to totally customize any view for a customer if needed (Else default view is shown). I have provided a way that I have been using for years [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74523733/customizing-cshtml-for-each-customer/74523791#74523791) using customizing a `RazorViewEngine`.